# How to get output when calling a contract method and signing it?

Tags: polkadot-js, smart-contract, api

I have a contract which I want to call using the polkadot{.js} extension.
To call the method successfully, you have to sign it.
When I am now signing a method, I have trouble reading out the value the method
should give me, when executed properly.

If I would not have to sign the method, I would read the output the follwing way:

```
const { output } = await contract.query.method(
    account.address,
    {
        gasLimit,
        storageDepositLimit,
    },
    variables
)

console.log(output.toHuman())
```

And the output would look smth like that:

> Ok('result here')

Now I have to sign the method first, and the code looks the following way:

```
const { output } = await contract.tx
    .method({ storageDepositLimit, gasLimit }, variables)
    .signAndSend(account.address, {signer: injector.signer},  result => {
    if (result.status.isInBlock) {
        console.log('in a block');
    } else if (result.status.isFinalized) {
      console.log('finalized');
      console.log(result.toHuman())
    }
})
```

The 'result.toHuman()' part does not give me the output of the method. And when I try to call 'output.toHuman()' it tells me that output is undefined.

How can I access the output of the method, when signing the execution prior?

Comment: First do a dry-run to get the result and if Ok(()) send as tx.
Check this answer:
https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/4233/567

Comment: Yes, that works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like P.Ossun said, the solution is to dry-run the contract first and
check the answer, then to run the contract again, this time making actual
changes on the blockchain.

[Here](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api-contract/start/contract.tx/#cost-estimation) you can find the documantation how to do the dry run.

The solution to my question would look the following way:

```
const { gasRequired, storageDeposit, result, output } = await contract.query.method(
    account.address,
    {
        gasLimit,
        storageDepositLimit,
    },
    variables
)

console.log(output.toHuman())

if(result.isOk){
    await contract.tx
        .method({ storageDepositLimit, gasLimit }, variables)
        .signAndSend(account.address, {signer: injector.signer},  result => {
        if (result.status.isInBlock) {
            console.log('in a block');
        } else if (result.status.isFinalized) {
            console.log('finalized');
        }
    })
}
```